# Is event attributes supported when JavaScript is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, events

If have this HTML code and the user's browser's JavaScript is disabled will the event attributes still work?

```
<button onclick='alert("You clicked the button!");'>Click</button>
```

If not is there a way to trigger events for users with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: no, the event wont be triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't capture any javascript if browser javascript is disable
            you can use  tag to give some information to enable javascript

```
<noscript>
 For full functionality of this site it is necessary to enable JavaScript.
 Here are the <a href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/" target="_blank">
 instructions how to enable JavaScript in your web browser</a>.
</noscript>
```

Comment: I mean if the browser's JavaScript is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

When JavaScript is disabled in a browser, it *means* that JavaScript code is not executed, whether it is in event attributes or elsewhere. In theory, you could use another client-side scripting language, but there is no realistic option (VBScript is IE-only, and besides, the odds are that if JavaScript is disabled, so is other client-side scripting in general).

However, some elements have event handling associated with them by HTML definitions. For example, an `<input type=submit>` element inside a form causes form submission when clicked on, and an `<a href=...>...</a>` element causes a link to be followed when clicked on. You cannot cause an alert popup to appear that way, though.